# Why calories table for 100g doesn't sum 100?

Tags: calories

I'm checking the calories for muesli for 100g:

Calories : 374 Kcal
protein: 7.5g
carbohydrate: 61.5g
fat: 5.3g

When I sum those 3, I get: 74.3%

What is the other 25.7 %

Comment: You're summing the weights of just the macros here. There's water, minerals and tons of other stuff in food. That's why people aren't always for IIFYM. Also we don't really do diet questions unrelated to exercise here, or math problems.

Comment: Ah sorry ! My first post. What a nice group ! I also have a lot of question about exercices ! And by the way thanks, you could put it as an anwser !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weight of all the macros in a food is not the total weight of the food. Most foods contain at least a little water, and minerals and plenty of other things. The left over quarter is all that other "stuff". For example, living (or at one point living, like chicken breast) things contain about 60% water. This percent is way higher for things like cucumber or jelly fish which are basically all water.